# How do you find out which program is using too much memory?

Tags: memory-usage

Ubuntu has been crashing on me recently. I think its because it runs out of memory so I ran the `free -m` command and found that my memory usage was really high. So then, i ran `top` to find the culprit, but the displayed processes were using less than 1.5% of memory. How do I know which program is making ubuntu crash/run out of memory? Below is the output:

```
shafee@shafee-pc:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3824       3714        110          0        978       1954
-/+ buffers/cache:        780       3044
Swap:           99          0         99

shafee@shafee-pc:~$ top
top - 02:12:14 up  1:24,  2 users,  load average: 0.16, 0.42, 1.49
Tasks: 182 total,   1 running, 181 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.9%us,  1.9%sy,  0.3%ni, 79.3%id, 15.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3916708k total,  3803848k used,   112860k free,  1002308k buffers
Swap:   102396k total,        0k used,   102396k free,  2001852k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
 4200 root      20   0  289m  53m  38m S    2  1.4   1:06.45 Xorg               
 5590 shafee    20   0 19348 1368  956 R    2  0.0   0:00.01 top                
    1 root      20   0 24124 2136 1264 S    0  0.1   0:02.05 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:24.23 ksoftirqd/0        
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0        
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1        
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.11 ksoftirqd/1        
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2        
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:03.89 ksoftirqd/2        
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3        
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.16 ksoftirqd/3        
   17 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset             
   18 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper            
   19 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 netns              
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 sync_supers        
shafee@shafee-pc:~$
```

Or is it normal to have 110mb of free memory and is my issue related to something else?

Comment: It looks like you also don't have enough swap. Recommended is around twice the size of your RAM

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are reading the output of `free` incorrectly. The Linux Kernel does a lot of its own memory management, in turn allocating more than it actually needs - so your true amount of "Free Memory" is `3044` located in the "Free" column of the `+/- Buffers/cache` line, making only 780 MB actually being consumed.

By default `top` will sort based on CPU consumption. You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to sort by percentage of memory consumed - giving you a better grasp of what software is using the memory allotted to the kernel.

---

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7873       3916       3956          0        231       1117
-/+ buffers/cache:       2567       5305
Swap:        12401          0      12401
```

And in top with memory sorted:

```
top - 17:05:18 up 2 days,  1:40,  4 users,  load average: 0.21, 0.14, 0.11
Tasks: 237 total,   1 running, 234 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.6%us,  0.8%sy,  0.1%ni, 96.7%id,  0.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8062420k total,  4013632k used,  4048788k free,   237204k buffers
Swap: 12699644k total,      292k used, 12699352k free,  1144752k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                          
 1632 root      20   0  884m 240m 6532 S    0  3.1   1:20.17 java                                                                                                                                                                             
 3911 marco     20   0 1011m 165m  22m S    0  2.1   9:20.62 chrome                                                                                                                                                                           
 3852 marco     20   0  770m 162m  45m S    0  2.1  14:59.59 chrome                                                                                                                                                                           
 1091 root      20   0  491m 160m 118m S    3  2.0  29:19.44 Xorg                                                                                                                                                                             
 1747 marco     20   0  659m 108m  34m S    1  1.4  18:43.92 compiz                                                                                                                                                                           
 3964 marco     20   0 1113m  99m  21m S    0  1.3  18:51.88 chrome                                                                                                                                                                           
 1759 marco     20   0  668m  94m  21m S    0  1.2   2:27.42 nautilus                                                                                                                                                                         
 3046 marco     20   0  788m  86m  26m S    0  1.1   1:22.96 evolution                                                                                                                                                                        
 1793 marco     20   0  647m  85m  18m S    0  1.1   0:12.74 shutter                                                                                                                                                                          
 1791 marco     20   0  404m  85m  13m S    0  1.1   5:19.51 bitcoin                                                                                                                                                                          
 2938 marco     20   0  809m  78m  31m S    0  1.0   1:01.07 empathy                                                                                                                                                                          
 9630 marco     20   0  265m  73m  19m S    1  0.9  12:41.52 skype                                                                                                                                                                            
 9618 marco     20   0  914m  64m  21m S    0  0.8   1:14.04 chrome                                                                                                                                                                           
 1777 marco     20   0  432m  64m  14m S    0  0.8   1:45.96 pastie
```

Finally to help you diagnose what the actual software is, try passing the `-c` flag to top: `top -c` as that will give you the full path, name, and parameters of the command running.

Comment: thanks :/ seems my crashes are related to something else then.

Comment: @Shafee You might want to open a new question then, outlining what is crashing and providing any relevant log files or details to see if we can assist you with resolving those crashes.

Comment: Wow. learnt yet something new again....cheers marco yet again!

Comment: See also http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following script to see total memory usage by individual applications in your GNU Linux system

http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4446/show-total-memory-usage-by-each-application-in-your-ubuntu-or-any-gnu-linux-system

Comment: Useful, but doesn't show all memory in use.

Answer (score 3):

You can start the application gnome-system-monitor
It's the best to find out how much ram is used by what apps, also how much cpu is used also.
You can change the priority of a process to run even faster , for example if you want to convert video etc etc.

Comment: ec2 does not have gnome-system-monitor on cmd line, is there a alternative ?

Comment: @Siddharth you can use `htop` which is a nicer version of top. Hit F6 to sort by e.g. CPU or RAM usage.

Comment: @Siddharth you can still install gnome-system-monitor on a system without GUI (will install quite a bit of dependencies though). Then, as long as you have Linux client, you can run it via X forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question but the information shows there is lots of memory available. You should be monitoring your memory usage though.

My favorite system monitor is `conky` and memory display is part of it:

[image: Conky.gif]

Total memory line shows 2.5 GiB out of 7.4 GiB is being used.

Detailed memory line shows:

- `Web Content` is using 7% of memory. This is a Firefox subprogram.
- `Firefox` itself is using 7% of memory
- `ffmpeg` is using 3% of memory. This is the `.gif` recorder `peek` making the video we are watching.

Conky is highly configurable and everyone's desktop looks different. You can google `conky` and get 787 thousand hits.

Answer (score 1):

In *Kubuntu* I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then sort things using field of interest: Memory, CPU, ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this challenge when working on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

**Let me add my 2 cents to this question**:

Your actual **free**/unallocated memory is **110MB**

The **buffer/cache/allocated** memory which is 3044 is actually free memory but it's already allocated.

This is what happens. As you use more applications on your laptop, your **buffer/cache/allocated** memory increases, by allocating more memory specifically to those applications. This memory increases to allow you to easily access those applications in memory, which increases performance.

However, newer applications may now have to struggle with the **free/unallocated** memory left, because the **buffer/cache/allocated** memory even though they are free, they have already been allocated to some set of applications that you are currently using.

I found some script online that helps you free up some **buffer/cache/allocated** memory for other applications to use without restarting your machine. You may have to run the script once a day/week.

```
free -h && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3 && sudo sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free -h
```

**Resources**: [How do you find out which program is using too much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/a/53339)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: very very   useful !