# Why does my application crash without updating the log file (used '> my.log')

Tags: bug-reporting, cpu-load, memory-usage, kill, top

I am running mCruiseOn Server, which is a java based server side application (sockets, multiple threads, memcached, mysql) on a Micro EC2. It has been crashing often. I suspect memory usage may have killed it.

[How to you find out which program is using too much memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53264/how-do-you-find-out-which-program-is-using-too-much-memory)

I read through this and it was very useful. Now I need to know if my application crashed due to memory shortage. Any system log that has that information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a well-designed application crashes due to lack of memory, it should give some useful information about this. Try running invoking the application from the Terminal, and examining the messages.

Comment: I wonder how the question was not good enough for someone.

Comment: @Siddharth Who knows. Maybe they didn't read carefully, and thought you were trying to [report a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (which would be [off-topic here](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)). In any case, you'll be happy to know that random upvotes tend to more than cancel out random downvotes (especially in terms of reputation gained/lost, since an upvote adds more rep than a downvote takes away).

Answer (score 0):

I was redirecting all output to a file using `> my.log &` and then using `tail -f my.log` to view all messages. For some reason all `e.printstacktrace` were not in the my.log. I was missing a `RuntimeException` and the exact root cause a `ArrayOutofboundException`.

Comment: It's unclear if this is intended as an explanation of the problem, or as an indication that you have not yet solved it. If the latter, then this should be an edit to your question (and you could leave a comment on my answer too if you want). Also, please note that you have accepted my answer, which means this question is considered to be "solved." If none of the answers here are sufficient to your needs yet, then I recommend un-accepting my answer (click the check mark again), so people know you're still looking for help.

Comment: However, if you now know the cause o the crash, you should [report that as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) rather than reopening this question (as Ask Ubuntu is [not a good place to *report* bugs](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)).

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I'll be more careful with my questions. That said, your answer helped me come back to my application rather than looking for a bug in the OS. My answer to my question is just a way to help someone understand what I did to solve my issue and was the root cause of my issue. I could not imagine that a > my.log, would not capture e.printstacktrace messages. Too report to consider I would say. Again, thanks for your help. This helped.

Comment: Error messages are typically written to stderr. `> file` only redirects stdout, so to get *all* output redirected to file, use `> file 2>&1`