# Copying to USB pen drive slows everything

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive, copy

Every time when I copy large files from my laptop to any pen drive (USB) on my Ubuntu 14.04, all processes slow down. *Even the mouse pointer* slows and is stuck. If I open multiple tasks, many of them stop responding. 
The copying also stops for a long time at *100%, 0 sec remaining*.

I am using Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu in which there is no problem in copying files.

*Useful Hardware Specification of my laptop* : HP Compaq 15-s103TX Notebook

- **Processor**
  Processor : Intel Core i3 4005U
  Clock Speed : 1.7GHz
  Chipset : HM87
  Cache   : 3MB
- RAM: 4 GB DDR3, 1600 MHz
- Graphic processor: NVIDIA GeForce 820M
- Dedicated graphics memory capacity: 2GB
- System architecture : 64-bit
- HDD: 1TB SATA 5400 RPM
- Number of USB 3.0 ports = 1 (same problem here)

Comment: Is there encryption or decryption happening? Perhaps you have an encrypted partition for Ubuntu, and that's taking extra processor time on those big data file transfers which isn't happening under Windows.

Comment: I don't have any encrypted partitions. But  I do have all the partitions (except root,home swap. which are in ext4 ) in  **NTFS**   format. This is because windows don't recognize ext 4 partitions.  All my friends (10-15) who are facing the same problem have NTFS partitions. Is this a problem??

Comment: Consider this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/397249/system-freezes-unresponsive-unusable-when-copying-large-file-to-usb

Comment: @Marc, if it was slow due to decrypting files on an encrypted partition, it would be slow *every time you used a file on that partition*, not just when copying the file to USB.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/572911/

Comment: @Olathe - Perhaps, but you'd notice it a lot more with the occasional very large file than you would with the thousands of very small files.

Answer (score 0):

Your system configuration looks good it doesn't matter, but check the number of process running and stop the process which occupies more memory.

I propose the best way to copying large files into Pen drive, is to use rsync.

```
rsync -r source/* destination
```

it is the efficient way use it.

For more information refer, have fun Bro...

1. [How do you find out which program is using too much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53264/how-do-you-find-out-which-program-is-using-too-much-memory)
2. [Learn About rsync.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync)

Comment: Also refer, [How to speed up rsync?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168442)
and Optionaly refer, [How To Setting Up NFS.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168442)

Comment: `rsync` is an awesome and underrated utility. It's the best backup program around as well!