# Ubuntu 18.04 uses different amount of memory on different machines

Tags: ram, 18.04, memory-usage

I have a **4GB** machine, and when launching Ubuntu 18.04 (gnome) on this machine, it uses **1.4GB** of ram just after booting.

I tried the same ISO on another machine with **8GB**, and it uses **3.6GB** of ram just after booting.

Why Ubuntu is having such behavior? Does Ubuntu do that to improve performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3.6GB is a lot for just the OS. Probably you have something memory-intensive running, like a web browser. Did you check the System Monitor for details?

Comment: it's a new installation, and I did the test just after the reboot, so I don't think there is processes that are eating memory.

Comment: Possibly useful: [How do you find out which program is using too much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/53264/301745)

Answer (score 2):

You could get a hint of what is happening with memory in those systems with

```
top -o %MEM
```

With that command you will get all processes sorted by memory usage. Maybe the additionnal memory is used for buffering ?