# What's the thing which uses RAM that much?

Tags: 18.04, ram

I have a server (with 8GB Ram) and no specific service is running, but 5GB of Ram is used
how can I detect what's the thing which uses the Ram that much?

[image]

See? 5GB is used, and the most used thing is `0.9%` of the memory. So, any idea how can I free that 5GB?

Comment: Have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/53264/how-do-you-find-out-which-program-is-using-too-much-memory

Comment: `echo 3 | sudo tee  /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` will free old buffers and such.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find out which program is using too much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53264/how-do-you-find-out-which-program-is-using-too-much-memory)